# Sqlite3 python no such table when insert data after table is created successfully

Tags: python, sqlite

Create Table

```
 sql_create_table = "CREATE TABLE employee (ID INTEGER, title TEXT, firstname TEXT, surname TEXT, email TEXT, salary INTEGER)"


def create_table(self):
try:
  self.get_connection()
  table = self.cur.execute(self.sql_create_table)  # Create table

  self.conn.commit()
  print('This table "Person" is already created!')

except Exception as e:
  print(e)
finally:
  self.conn.close()
```

Insert Record:

```
def get_connection(self):

  self.conn = sqlite3.connect("People.db")
  self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
  print("db connection is set up")



def insert_data(self):
    try:
      self.get_connection()
      acc = tuple(str(emp).split("\n"));
      self.cur.execute(self.sql_insert, ('1', 'Miss', 'Susan', 'Willian', 'susanwilan@gmail.com', '3000')) # HERE comes the error!!!!!!!!

      self.conn.commit()
      print("Inserted data successfully")
      except Exception as e:
       print(e)
      finally:
       self.conn.close()
```

Issue:

The table is able to create without issue, but when I try to insert the date into the table there is an issue, it keep saying that **there is no such table: employee**

I thought it was the path issue, the creating path and the path to read the DB is not the same but seems it is not the case

Comment: Why are you wrapping everything in try/except?

Comment: You're not showing the value of `self.sql_insert` but the table you created at the top is called `people`, not `employee`.

Comment: @Woodford sorry, my bad, I was trying to change the code a bit when posting the question.

Comment: @roganjosh it is the practice from my home work they comes in the first place

Comment: Could you convert this into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It looks like all you've given us is the class definition. If you could show exactly how this class is being used, it would help us reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @Chris I replaced the emp with a concrete tuple

Comment: @ssa, I'm still not able to run your code though. Ideally you would give us something we could copy/paste into a file and run to reproduce the same issue. Please try doing this yourself and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: As Woodford mentioned, we need to know the value of `self.sql_insert` at a minimum. I can try converting everything you've given into a class and then try using the class, but I don't know what to use for `self.sql_insert` to reproduce the issue when `insert_data` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer


Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///{DB_PATH}")

class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Title = Column(String)
    firstname = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    salary = Column(Integer)
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = 0
        self.Title = ''
        self.firstname = ''
        self.surname = ''
        self.email = ''
        self.salary = 0.0

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

More info here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html